# A Python package using caching

Tags: python, caching, package

It is possible to use the built-in `pkgutil` package to use its `pkgutil.get_data` to get data packaged with the package.

My case is a bit different.

I would like to allow a platform-independent way to allow storing of data done by my package, but not actually distribute anything at installation.

When the data is older than, let's say, 1 day, when a new conversion is being done it should refresh this cache.

Code might help:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

cache_path = "XXX/here"
with open(cache_path) as f:
    cached_data = json.load(f)

def convert(value, from_type, to_type):
    pair = from_type + "-" to_type

    now = datetime.now()
    too_old = (now + relativedelta(days=1)).isoformat()
    if pair not in cached_data or too_old < cached_data[pair]['last_updated']:
        cached_data[pair] = get_new_value(pair)
        with open(cache_path, "w") as f:
            json.dump(cached_data, f)

    return value * float(cached_data[pair]['value'])
```

So how to choose `cache_path`?

Answer (score 0):

The built in `tempfile` module will help you here.

```
import tempfile
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as cache_path_fh:
    <do stuff>
```

Deletion/cleanup will have to be done manually with `delete=False` since you want the file to persist beyond the scope of the file handle.

By default the files go under `/tmp` or the system's temporary dir, which can be adjusted. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html?highlight=tempfile#module-tempfile).

Comment: Problem is that in /tmp they will be deleted after restart for example. It shouldn't really be a tmp file. So where would we store it?

Comment: Up to you really. Per docs, directory path can be adjusted. Typically on linux data files go under /opt or /var/opt or under the running user's home. Windows I cannot say, user's "home" directory maybe.